# Infinite Redirect Loop on Google One Tap Signin

Tags: html, google-api, google-one-tap

I'm having trouble finding any documentation in regards to Google One Tap UX and how to persist signin state after a signin redirect. I am using the html api, check the code here:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    let target = document.getElementById('google-signin');
    target.innerHTML = '<div id="g_id_onload" data-client_id="x" data-context="signin" data-login_uri="https://x/account/google/callback" data-auto_select="true" data-itp_support="true"></div>';
    var s = document.createElement("script");
        s.src = 'https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client';
        
        document.head.appendChild(s);
        
        console.log('appended script', s);
    }, 30000);
</script>
```

Essentially I am delaying this signin popup for 30 seconds, that part works fine but soon after this is what happens:

1. Sign in occurs
2. Redirect happens
3. Server redirects back to the referer page
4. After 30 seconds the process starts again

I would have assumed the google sdk would set a cookie or something somewhere but I guess it does not, either that I'm supposed to handle persisting signin state through my own means. I just want to know the correct approach here.

My question is: **How does google know if a user has already signed in using Google One Tap UX?**

Answer (score 0):

Figured out a solution. Google allows you to put a property on your div tag called `data-skip_prompt_cookie="yourcookie"` [this will skip the one tap prompt if that cookie is present with a truthy value](https://developers.google.com/identity/gsi/web/reference/html-reference#data-skip_prompt_cookie).

What I did was on my server callback in asp.net I added a cookie to the response. This ensures the prompt is only disabled once someone actually signs in.

```
Response.Cookies.Append(
            "yourcookie", "true");
```

This ensures when my server redirects back to the originating page, the cookie exists and the one tap does not show up again